# android xml, crash of the custom view in a layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

I designed a simple compass app,
at the first step, I wrote the app with a single view(the compass view) and it worked just fine. I made a new instance of my custom compass-view, and I used setcontent(mView).

now im trying to use layouts, and I just cant make it work! everytime i try, the app crashes.

here is the code:

### the custom-view:

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
public float azimut;
Paint paint = new Paint();
public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    azimut=0;
  };
public CustomDrawableView(Context context, float Azimut) {
  super(context);
  paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
  paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
  paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  azimut=Azimut;
};
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.compassarrowbitmap);
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    int centerx = width/2;
    int centery = height/2;
    int imHeight=200;
    int imWidth=200;
    Bitmap arrow = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap,imHeight , imWidth, false);
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG); //Saving the canvas and later restoring it so only this image will be rotated.
    canvas.rotate(-azimut*360/(2*3.14159f), centerx, centery);
    canvas.drawBitmap(arrow, centerx-imWidth/2, centery-imHeight/2, null);
    canvas.restore();           
  }
}
```

### the xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<FrameLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<org.example.compassTest.CustomDrawableView
    android:id="@+id/compassview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

### the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
Float azimut=(float) 0;  // View to draw a compass
CustomDrawableView mCompassView;    
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
Sensor accelerometer;
Sensor magnetometer;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.mCompassView = (CustomDrawableView) findViewById(R.id.compassview);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    magnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {  }

float[] mGravity;
float[] mGeomagnetic;
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        mGravity = event.values;
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
            mGeomagnetic = event.values;
    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            azimut = orientation[0]; // orientation contains: azimut, pitch and roll
        }
    }
    this.mCompassView.azimut=azimut;
    this.mCompassView.invalidate();
}
}
```

**** log:

```
    01-07 04:40:54.957: W/dalvikvm(18101): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c431f8)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
**01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.compasstest/org.example.compasstest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class org.example.compassTest.CustomDrawableView****
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class org.example.compassTest.CustomDrawableView
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:271)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at org.example.compasstest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    ... 11 more
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.compassTest.CustomDrawableView
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
01-07 04:40:54.957: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Please provide the error log.

Comment: where can i find the log??

Comment: Eclipse > DDMS Perspective > Log Cat

Comment: When your app crashes it should display the errors for you. Highlight the red rows, press Ctrl+C, then paste them in your question.

Comment: seem like eclipse doesnt like the way i tryed to use my custom-view in the xml file

Comment: Just implement all three View constructors.I think you forgot to add one that receives the parameters from layout xml.

Comment: can you plz be more specific.... what constructor do i need to add? what other parameters should he recieve?      thanks allot!

Answer (score 5):

I think that you are missing this constructor :

```
public CustomDrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

You are trying to build the view from layout xml passing parameters,but you don't have any constructor that can receive them.

Comment: i dont understande.. I thought that the xml will build the view using the constructor : CustomDrawableView(Context context), without passing any parameters... thats why i initialized azimut=0, and changed it only from outside the class in the void onSensorChanged method of the main. how can the layout xml pass parameters?

Comment: <org.example.compassTest.CustomDrawableView
    android:id="@+id/compassview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" /> ==> You passing here all android tags : id,width and height

Comment: ohh... ok, so.. how exactly do i handle it? do i need to specify layout_height and the others in the constructor?

Comment: You already receiving this parameters from layout xml so.Yeah and please mark my post as an answer please.

Comment: and can you plz help me with the constructor? how do i handle those parameters? or maybe refer me to an example?.. thanks

Comment: Firstly you need to understand by yourself if you need to handle them or not and than decide what to do with them.Good luck!

Comment: I tryed to add the constructor, I imported the android.util.AttributeSet and added the constructor: {    `public CustomDrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        azimut=0;
      };`        and the app crashed again.... any ideas??

Comment: It crashes with the same error as before?If yes than why did you marked this post as answer and if not please provide the error log.